# Div Size Inside ItemTemplate Repeater ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have 3 div tags which I would like to show side by side in one row.

They are located inside a main div:

```
<div class="dvItemContainer">
  <div class="nameContainer">content-1</div>
  <div class="quantityDiv">Content-2</div>
  <div class="dvLnkContainer">Content-3</div>
</div>

The classes are:

.dvItemContainer
{
    width:250px;
    float:right;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width:250px;
}
.nameContainer
{
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    max-width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.quantityDiv
{
    width:60px;
    float:right;
}
.dvLnkContainer
{
    width:40px;
    float:right;
    right:0;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

This code defined inside a user control which I use as Itemtemplate unside asp:Repeter control.

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <div style="width:100%; display:inline;" runat="server">
      <prod:ProductItemTagName ID="productItem" width="100%" runat="server" />
   </div>
</ItemTemplate
```

Somehow these divs take one whole row for each other.

For example it shows it like that:

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

the problem is style="width:100%; display:inline;" from 
`<div style="width:100%; display:inline;" runat="server">`
div by default is display:block element so you don't need to give it width of 100% 
and if you use display:inline the width won't be effective

so change it with `style="width:100%;display:inline-block"`

the display:inline-block used to make this div wrap the floated div 
and we gave it width as the display:inline-block removes the default width